# Function is printing multiple times

Tags: python, function, recursion

I've written a function that takes as input a positive integer n and recursively returns a list of factorial values 1!, 2!, . . . , n!.

However, I can't get it to print the list just a single time. I've tried placing the print statement in various loops/locations and it always prints at least 3 times. I've also tried printing the function but it returns 'None', it only seems to print if I have  a print statement in the function. Why is this?

Here is my code:

```
def calc_Factorial(my_list, n, x, e):

    if not my_list:
        my_list.append(n-(n-1))
        calc_Factorial(my_list, n, x, e)
    else:
        if len(my_list) < n:
             my_list.append(my_list[e]*x)
             calc_Factorial(my_list, n, x+1, e+1)

    if len(my_list) == n:
        print(my_list)


e = 0
x = 2
n = int(input('Enter number: '))
my_list = []
calc_Factorial(my_list, n, x, e)
```

Comment: `my_list.append(n-(n-1))` : isn't this just 1? Also, why not just use a for loop instead? I don't know why you need to repeat the function over and over.

Comment: Yes it will always be 1, not sure exactly why I wrote it like that. And the idea was to practice recursion rather than just doing it with a for loop, which is why it looks messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value is being printed multiple times because you are using `print` inside the recursive function. You should return instead of printing inside the recursive function.

```
def calc_Factorial(my_list, n, x, e):

  if not my_list:
    my_list.append(n-(n-1))
    return calc_Factorial(my_list, n, x, e)
  else:
    if len(my_list) < n:
         my_list.append(my_list[e]*x)
         return calc_Factorial(my_list, n, x+1, e+1)

    if len(my_list) == n:
        return (my_list)


e = 0
x = 2
n = int(input("Enter number: "))
my_list = []
print (calc_Factorial(my_list, n, x, e))
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the print statement to `return my_list`:

```
def calc_Factorial(my_list, n, x, e):
    if not my_list:
        my_list.append(n-(n-1))
        calc_Factorial(my_list, n, x, e)
    else:
        if len(my_list) < n:
             my_list.append(my_list[e]*x)
             calc_Factorial(my_list, n, x+1, e+1)
    if len(my_list) == n:
        return my_list


>>> calc_Factorial(my_list, n, x, e)
[1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def calc_Factorial(my_list, n, x, e):

    if not my_list:
        my_list.append(n-(n-1))
        return calc_Factorial(my_list, n, x, e)
    else:
        if len(my_list) < n:
             my_list.append(my_list[e]*x)
             return calc_Factorial(my_list, n, x+1, e+1)

    if len(my_list) == n:
        print(my_list)
        return my_list
```

Your **key problem** here is that you should `return calc_Factorial(my_list, n, x+1, e+1)` every time when your call your `recursive`. If you don't `return` to the recursion, the rest of the code will be executed eventually. That's why you saw multiple `print`.

As long as you call recursive with return in this case. You should always only see one time print (even through you don't `return my_list`:

```
if len(my_list) == n:
    print(my_list)
```

But usually in the recursive function, people just return the value you want eventually. However, you can use print serve the purpose of debugging.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is because of this part:

```
if len(my_list) < n:
     my_list.append(my_list[e]*x)
     calc_Factorial(my_list, n, x+1, e+1) 


if len(my_list) == n:
    print(my_list)
```

After the first if statement, the function will continue to execute, and now 
n == len(my_list) so the list will be printed. (In effect this means that every call to the function will end up printing something)